# Why is only 3.2GBs out of 5 showing up?

Tags: ram

I have 64Bit Ubuntu installed, and a MSI Graphics card.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?[image]

Comment: How are you determining that you only have 3.2Gb? Please post the output of `uname -a` and `free -m` here. Both of these commands are run in the terminal which you can open by doing `ctrl+alt+t`

Comment: @crasic he's going by the Mem line's total column.

Comment: what does your BIOS think you have for memory?

Comment: 5gb show in bios

Comment: What does this show  

cat /proc/meminfo

Comment: Providing the topmost hundred lines of your `/var/log/messages` file to look how your system sees the memory map would greatly help. Use `head -100 /var/log/messages` and please show the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check in the motherboard BIOS for an option similar to "map around memory hole." Your motherboard's chipset may not support this option.

Older, especially laptop, chipsets (for example, the Intel 945p chipset) did not support true 64 bit memory addressing and had a ceiling of 4GB even in 64 bit mode. If that is the case with your system then this is a hardware limitation that can't be addressed without replacing the chipset (motherboard.)

Comment: No option in BIOS, I guess it could be the processor

Comment: @TheX What is the motherboard's chipset?

Comment: @TheX @Amazed it might be easier to just post the model of the motherboard so we can look up the chipset

Comment: I will have to look will let you know

Answer (score 2):

Is it an integrated VGA? In that case, some will share the main memory, so it won't be available to applications.

Comment: Dedicated video as I mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

Is the missing memory on the graphics card or memory in your computer?  How have you determined that only 3.2GBs are showing up?

If it's a matter of available memory, you might check System Monitor (in System Settings) and look under the Processes tab, and then click "Memory" to put the processes in order so you can easily see which are using the most memory.  The Resources tab will show total memory in your system, as well as how much is being used.

Answer (score -3):

You need to install pae kernel. This will allow usage of memory on a computer larger than 4GB

Most times you can install with:

sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae

Once you restart you should see the correct memory size.

Comment: This is invalid. The post already states that he is using 64-bit Ubuntu